# How to specify which of my apps on Heroku should be associated to a domain?

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain

I have `www.example.com` associated with `APP-A` on Heroku.

I want `www.example.com` instead do be directed to `APP-B` on Heroku.

In addition to changing my DNS settings to point to `APP-B.herokuapp.com` I *assume* I have to tell heroku about this change as well.

*Normally* [you add a domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#custom-subdomains) on Heroku with the command `heroku domains:add www.example.com`.

**But how do I specify that it is for `APP-B` that I want to set `www.example.com`?**

This didn't work: `heroku domains:add www.example.com --app APP-B`, Heroku tells me "Invalid arguments: "-app"."

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameter you want is `-a app-name`, so `heroku domains:add -a app-b www.example.com`

Here's a an example from the article on moving a custom domain on an app migrated to Europe

```
$ heroku domains:remove -a sourceapp www.example.com
Removing www.example.com from sourceapp... done

$ heroku domains:add -a targetapp www.example.com
Adding www.example.com to targetapp... done
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration#custom-domains

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you typed in `heroku domains:add www.example.com --app APP-B`. The error you show looks like the one you get if you type `heroku domains:add www.example.com -app APP-B`.

`heroku domains:add www.example.com --app APP-B` is the right way to add a domain. However, as [friism](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2942/friism) mentioned, you will need to remove the domain from `APP-A`. Heroku does not allow for adding the same domain to two different apps.